# Ionic/AngularJS HTTP Response Header is null on Safari/Chrome/Desktop Browsers

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, httprequest

I'm trying to get the header of a HTTP-Response.
I can get the header on the iPhone without any problems.
But my browser just gets null. Using the Safari Developer Console I can see, that there is the header I want to get. Somehow I can't get the header in AngularJS.

```
$http.post("/login", loginData)
     .then(function(response){
           console.log(response.headers("X-AUTH-TOKEN"));
           })
```

Comment: I believe it must be response.headers("X-AUTH-TOKEN")

Comment: i fixed it, there is still no header.

Comment: Are you sure that this is response header and not request header? Can you access to another response header this way?

Comment: I have also made a test page and can't reproduce your issue http://ypnh.shkryob.webfactional.com/headers/